# Android using Buttons for navigation (intent)

Tags: android, button, android-intent

Will there be any complications if I use buttons to navigate through my app (launch different activities)? I've tried using tabhost but if I want to change something within the tab, there might be some difficulties involved due to the tabactivitygroup being deprecated. If buttons work just fine, I can just repeat them in all the activities. I noticed a slight lag in changing activities by using this method though.

Comment: What complications are you worried about? You can create an intent and pass data if you need in the onClickListener. I don't think the lag is from using buttons necessarily but may have to do with something in your listener or otherwise. I would say that what you use to start the activity isn't as important as how you start the activity

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried work with Fragments (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) instead lauching different activities? You can use the button as you want, in an activity, and the main content can be changing using fragments. This could improving your layouts performance.